# Why is false returned before the triggering variable equals the triggering value in Ruby? almostIncreasingSequence Codefights

Tags: arrays, ruby, lis

One of the tools I'm using to improve coding is [Codefights](https://codefights.com/). I've been stuck on the same problem for several days now and could use some help figuring it out. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here are the instructions from CodeFights:

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is
>   possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more
>   than one element from the array.
>
> Example
>
> For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
>   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;
>
> There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to
>   get a strictly increasing sequence.
>
> For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
>   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.
>
> You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing
>   sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly
>   increasing sequence [1, 3].
>
> Input/Output
>
> [time limit] 4000ms (rb) [input] array.integer sequence
>
> Constraints: 2 ≤ sequence.length ≤ 105,
>   -105 ≤ sequence[i] ≤ 105.
>
> [output] boolean
>
> Return true if it is possible to remove one element from the array in
>   order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return false.

Below is the code I'm trying. I dropped in `puts "#{prev}"` a few times to see what `prev` is set to originally, after a `1` is added to `wrong` and at the very end, so the last `prev` recorded.

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence)
  prev = [sequence[0], sequence[1]].min
  puts "#{prev}"
  wrong = 0
  (sequence.length - 1).times do |num|
    if prev < sequence[num + 1]
      prev = sequence[num + 1]
    else
      wrong += 1
      return false if wrong == 2
      puts "#{prev}"
    end
  end
  puts "#{prev}"
  true
end
```

This is the only test that won't pass right now:

```
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 5, 6])
```

This should be *true* because `99` can be pulled out and the increasing sequence can continue. But `false` is being returned seemingly after `wrong` is only added to once.

The code should return `false` if `wrong == 2` From the `puts "#{prev}"` output, I can see that `prev` originates at `1` and a `wrong` is triggered when `99` is more than `5` and since `wrong` should only be at `1` I don't understand why it returns `false` immediately. I can get this test to pass if I set `prev = sequence[num - 1]` after a `wrong` is added to the first time, but then a lot of other tests won't pass. Here is a list of the other tests I'm trying. Most are the tests that Codefights requires you to pass before you can move to the next practice code.

```
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2])) #true
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 1, 2])) #false
(almostIncreasingSequence([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) #true
(almostIncreasingSequence([0, -2, 5, 6]) )#true
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6])) #false
(almostIncreasingSequence([40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30])) #false
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6])) #true
(almostIncreasingSequence([100, 200, 300, 400, 99, 500, 600])) #true
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])) #false
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 4, 10, 4, 2])) #false
(almostIncreasingSequence( [1, 1, 1, 2, 3])) #false
(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 1])) #true
(almostIncreasingSequence([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1])) #false
```

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like wrong is only being added once because your `puts` comes after the `return` so it's never being called. Moving it before the return reveals that wrong is in fact being incremented twice.

The core of your problem is that when you increment wrong, your `prev` value stays set to `99` which makes every subsequent value wrong. You do need to set `prev` to `sequence[num - 1]` to prevent this from happening, but like you said, this causes errors. That's because when you remove a bad number from an array (ie `[1, 2, 1, 2] -> [1, 1, 2]` you need to check again to see if the two now-consecutive numbers work together, which in this case they do not.

You could fix that, but then you'd hit another error with situations like [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`where your starting`prev` value isn't actually your first value.

Ultimately you're going to hit a lot of bugs because the logic behind your solution is complex and unintuitive for a human to follow. You *could* eventually reach your answer following this method, but you might want to revisit the problem and redesign your code from scratch.